# how to stop button from become clickable after certain counter value?

Tags: actionscript-3

I try to make increase and decrease button but I want to make that if the increase button hit the max value it will become unavailable and stop the user from interact with the increase button and vice versa with the decrease button.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

a1.visible=true;
a2.visible=false;
a3.visible=false;
plus.visible=false;
minus.visible=false;
final var clickCounter:Number=0;

e1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, decider);

function decider(event:MouseEvent):void{
    plus.visible=true;
    minus.visible=true;

    if (a1.visible==true){
        plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changer1);
        plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, increaser1);
        minus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changer1);
        minus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, decreaser1);
    }
}

function increaser1(event:MouseEvent):void{
    clickCounter++;
    if(clickCounter==3){
        plus.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changer1);
        plus.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, increaser1);
        minus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changer1);
        minus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, decreaser1);
    }
}

function decreaser1(event:MouseEvent):void{
    clickCounter--;
    if(clickCounter==-1){
        plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changer1);
        plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, increaser1);
        minus.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, changer1);
        minus.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, decreaser1);
    }
}

function changer1(event:MouseEvent):void{
     if(clickCounter==0){
          trace("1");
     }
     if(clickCounter==1){
        trace("2");
     }
     if(clickCounter==2){
        trace("3");
     }
}
```

This code manages to do what I want to archive but when I click the increase button more than 3 times and try to click decrease button, it will take time to decrease it.

Comment: "it will take time" -> How *much* time? How much time did you *expect* it to take?

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler than you did it, actually.

```
var clickCounter:int = 2;

arrangeButtons();

plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlusMinus);
minus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onPlusMinus);

function onPlusMinus(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Check for non-mouse interactions.
    if (!e.target.mouseEnabled) return;

    // Change the value based on which botton was clicked.
    clickCounter += ((e.currentTarget == plus)? 1: -1);

    // Adjust buttons to current counter value.
    arrangeButtons();

    // Output the values.
    trace(clickCounter + 1);
}

function arrangeButtons():void
{
    // Enable and disable buttons on margin values.
    minus.mouseEnabled = (clickCounter > 0);
    plus.mouseEnabled = (clickCounter < 2);

    // Display enabled/disabled status.
    minus.alpha = (minus.mouseEnabled? 1: 0.5);
    plus.alpha = (plus.mouseEnabled? 1: 0.5);
}
```

Comment: What the meaning of plus.mouseEnable? 1: 0.5;  ?

Comment: @Zero99 It is called a **ternary** operator: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#conditional I edited my post to outline them with **( )** brackets so they are more obviously readable. Simply, I tell the unavailable buttons to go half-transparent to highlight their unavailable status.

Comment: @Organis Also alter the `enabled` property, or else one can tab to that button and slam space overflowing the counter. One of the old bugs in games, namely in Bloons TD 1.

Comment: @Zero99 Set **stage.stageFocusRect = false;** (https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#stageFocusRect). Also I updaded my code to take this into account.

Comment: @Zero99 Additionally, you can set **plus.tabEnabled = false;** and **minus.tabEnabled = false;** to exclude them from being focused when user presses the **TAB** key.

Comment: @Organis is there a way to set the button into alpha 0.5 when first time the code run

Comment: and is there away to start the counter at specific value like 2

Comment: @Zero99 Edited my post. For this thing to do you just need to move the arrangements to a separate method so you can call it without specifically doing +-1 to counter.